# Jquery Click not working on test server

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, click

I'm kind of stuck and need some help.  I've got the following code that I can get to work in a test document, but once it gets on my test server, it loads as it's supposed to, but then the `fadeOut` click doesn't work.

```
 /* -- Show SignUp -- */

$(document).ready(function() {
      function showBox() {
        $("#box").fadeIn(500).removeClass('hidden');
      };
          setTimeout(showBox, 3000);
    });

/* -- Hide SignUp -- */

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#close").click(function(){
       $("#box").fadeOut(500);
   });
});
```

Comment: The click event on your `close` button is not being registered. Also why do you have `$(document).ready` twice?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `preventDefault`:`If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.`

```
$("#close").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#box").fadeOut(500);
});
```

#### Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: I think that makes sense but that doesn't justify why it would work in a test document and not on the server.

Comment: There is no sense to prevent default behavior for this context since it's not an issue of this problem.

Comment: I copy and paste this code in the Dev Tools on the test server and works as expected...

Answer (score 0):

From your code I see that event handler had been installed earlier, than element appeared on that page, so in this case it's necessary to use `.live`-type event handlers (to have it worked for all elements which will appear now or in the future).

Try to use following code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#close", function() {
  $("#box").fadeOut(500);
});
```

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/): As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Comment: Where you see `live()`?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Jquery `.live()` method is used for attaching an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future http://api.jquery.com/live/.

Comment: @OlegMeleshko: ZakariaAcharki is asking where did you get the reference to live function in the current context ?

Comment: @DinoMyte current context? We have `setTimeout` which will work later than installing event handler. Look [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to get more details.